# How can read data of other users (not user.uid) from firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read the data of not authenticated users from firestore
collection location is users->swipes->id
[image]

my attemp not success

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users",id,"swipes"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

I want to read id in swipes , not from user.uid
here 3 users in users
if want to read from user.uid , it is easy

```
collection(db, "users",user.id,"swipes")
```

if want to read from others users
I confuse
plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the `swiped` subcollection from all users, you'll want to [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). This type of operation reads all collections with a specific name.

In your case that'd be:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionGroup(db, "swipes"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```